What’s the State of the Art in Traffic Light Control Using Reinforcement Learning? Ideas for Master’s Thesis?
I’m currently planning my Master’s thesis and I’m interested in the application of RL to traffic light control systems.
I’ve come across research using different algorithms. However, I wanted to know:

What’s the current state of the art in this field? Are there any notable papers, benchmarks, or real-world implementations?

What challenges or gaps exist that still need to be addressed? For instance, are there issues with scalability, real-time adaptability, or multi-agent cooperation?

Any ideas for innovation? Are there promising RL algorithms that haven’t been applied yet in this domain? Could I explore hybrid approaches (e.g., combining RL with heuristic methods)? What about incorporating new types of data, like real-time pedestrian or cyclist behavior?


I’d really appreciate any insights, links to resources, or general advice on what direction I could take to contribute meaningfully to this field.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Please, ask only one question per post, otherwise your post will most likely be closed as "too broad". Also, avoid asking for opinions and recommendations, but ask for facts, if possible. Career path recommendation is off-topic here and I think if you ask for ideas for a master's thesis that falls into that off-topic.
